# Local notifications not working when app is breaked on Huawei device [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, notifications, huawei-mobile-services

I have created a Xamarin.Forms app, but I am oriented to android platform. I have released the app in 2 devices: **Samsung (Android 6.0 API 23) and Huawei (Android 6.0 API 23)**, the problem is on the huawei device, which when I want to create a local notification that it needs to be displayed when app is breaked, (by creating a broadcast receiver, etc) it is not displayed, otherwise on samsung it is, im sure that the problem is not on the code (is obvious, the code is not specialized on an specific device), so I believe more that the problem is on my huawei device, any suggestions for this problem??

**CODE FOR CREATING THE NOTIFICATIONS**

Method that is called when user click on “notify button” to shedule repeated notificacions:

```
 public static void EstablishNotification(long startSeconds)
            => alarmManager.SetRepeating(
                AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup,
                SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + (startSeconds * 1000),
                3600 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

**Broadcast receiver on binded to intent on alarm manager**

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent?.Extras != null)
            {
                title = intent.Extras.GetString(AndroidNotificationManager.TitleKey);
                message = intent.Extras.GetString(AndroidNotificationManager.MessageKey);
            }

            var id = intent.Extras.GetInt(AndroidNotificationManager.ID);

            Intent _intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(SplashActivity));
            _intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
            _intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);
            _intent.PutExtra(ID, id); 

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(
                AndroidApp.Context,
                id, _intent,
           PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
               .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
               .SetContentTitle(title)
               .SetContentText(message)
               .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.SortexAppIcon))
               .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.SortexAppIcon)
               .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

            manager = 
                (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(
                    AndroidApp.NotificationService);

            var notification = builder.Build();
            manager.Notify(messageId, notification);
```

Comment: Dis you created notification channel?

Comment: @AndroDevil yes

Comment: Is it working on any other devices coming with android 8.0 ?

Comment: @AndroDevil I haven’t tried yet

Comment: Please check it on other device with android 8.0. So that we can isolate the problem

Comment: I can’t do it since I don’t have one and I can’t prove the virtual machine for Android that VS provides

Comment: update your post with code, then we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Coz I can't just tell the solution for the problem that is causing for someone with some device only.

Comment: @SatyamKamboj post edited, can you check now please?

Comment: You can find answers to your every question here. Have a look at it.   https://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/

Answer (score 0):

[The solution is specified over this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/404014#Comment_404014)

Answer (score 0):

Methods,Firstly, Find "Settings" in the mobile phone, click to enter, and find "notification management". Second, Click to enter "notice management", which includes "notice management" and "suspended window management",  showing"notice management".
Forth, In "notice management", find the application which need to be opened. Click "enter" , the corresponding options will be displayed,selectting "prompt" or "allow".

Following is a detailed Chinese text and picture introduction,
https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1695787110911971788.html